# Can I change the suffix of a work in a direct quote?

Tags: suffixes, quotations

Okay so the quote I am using is "... shielding the public from the messy, imprecise consequences of a war—making the coverage incomplete, and even deceptive." Am I able to change shielding to shield? If so, do I have to show that I changed it and how would I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can change it as long as you indicate appropriately that you made a change. Your style guide (if you are using one) may specify a certain way to do this, usually involving square brackets.

For example, here is what the book [Legal Writing in Plain English: A Text with Exercises](https://books.google.com/books?id=reZf9nzoiSQC&pg=PA162) says:

> Use a pair of empty brackets to show the deletion of part of a word

As strange as it looks (and it's [no mystery](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1200621/6083675) why it looks strange to me), your quote then becomes:

> "... shield[] the public from the messy, imprecise consequences of a war—making the coverage incomplete, and even deceptive."

Comment: How do you change _shields_ to _shielding_? :)

Comment: @EdwinAshworth It's "shied[ing]"; this is covered in [this page I also linked to in my post](https://books.google.com/books?id=reZf9nzoiSQC&pg=PA162).